# Invoke() does not get called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code:

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject deathEffect;
    public float health = 4f;
    public static int EnemiesAlive = 0;
    public int loadToScene;

    void Start ()
    {
        EnemiesAlive++;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D colInfo)
    {
        if (colInfo.relativeVelocity.magnitude > health)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    void Die ()
    {
        Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        EnemiesAlive--;

        if (EnemiesAlive <= 0)
        {
            Debug.Log ("LEVEL WON!");
            Invoke("ChangeScene",2f);
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    void ChangeScene()
    {
        Debug.Log ("Hello");
        loadToScene = 1;
        SceneManager.LoadScene (loadToScene);
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me out why `Invoke()` does not work? I wanted to add 2 seconds delay before changing scene once the condition `(EnemiesAlive <= 0)` is fulfilled. `Debug.Log ("LEVEL WON!");` is outputted while `Debug.Log ("Hello");` is not. I know I can use `StartCoroutine` also but I wanted to use `Invoke()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are calling the Destroy(gameObject) like [m.rogalski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43634349/3785314) mentioned and it does not have a chance of executing `Invoke("ChangeScene",2f);`.

However, I have a feeling that you want to destroy that Object right away without waiting because you want stuff(such as `OnCollisionEnter2D`) in that script to stop running but at the-same time want to load your scene later on.

If this is the case then you have to put the loading function in a **separate script** attached to a **separate GameObject**. This script will not destroy when you call `Destroy(gameObject)`.

**1**.Create a new GameObject called *"SceneLdObj"*.

**2**.Attach the script below to the "SceneLdObj" GameObject.

```
public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    int loadToScene = 1;
    public void ChangeScene(int sceneLevel)
    {
        loadToScene = sceneLevel;
        Invoke("loadScene", 2f);
    }

    private void loadScene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(loadToScene);
    }
}
```

Add the script below to the script in your question:

```
 SceneLoader sceneLoader;

 void Start()
 {
     sceneLoader = GameObject.Find("SceneLdObj").GetComponent<SceneLoader>();
 }
```

Now, you can the load function from your Die function and it will still work even though the GameObject is already destroyed.

```
void Die()
{
    Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    EnemiesAlive--;

    if (EnemiesAlive <= 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("LEVEL WON!");
        //Call that function from another script
        sceneLoader.ChangeScene(1);
    }
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

This should be your new `Enemy` script:

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject deathEffect;
    public float health = 4f;
    public static int EnemiesAlive = 0;
    public int loadToScene;
    SceneLoader sceneLoader;

    void Start ()
    {
        sceneLoader = GameObject.Find("SceneLdObj").GetComponent<SceneLoader>();
        EnemiesAlive++;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D colInfo)
    {
        if (colInfo.relativeVelocity.magnitude > health)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    void Die ()
    {
        Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        EnemiesAlive--;

        if (EnemiesAlive <= 0)
        {
            Debug.Log ("LEVEL WON!");
            //Call that function from another script
            sceneLoader.ChangeScene(1);
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    void ChangeScene()
    {
        Debug.Log ("Hello");
        loadToScene = 1;
        SceneManager.LoadScene (loadToScene);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for correctly predict my intention. I forgot to mention earlier. I have successfully follow your steps up to "Add the script below..." but I am not sure on how to add your given code into my code. I tried and get an error on SceneLoader. Do I need to declare SceneLoader first? What type should I declare it with?

Comment: @jer Modified the the last part of the instruction directly into your `Enemy` script. Just copy that. As long as you created the `SceneLoader` script and attached it to new GameObject called *"SceneLdObj"*. This should work.

Comment: I just recently use stackoverflow.com. I do not know I have to accept. I am sorry. Thanks for the heads up. :)

Comment: That's fine. You only do so if the answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Invoke` is in fact getting called but your object is destroyed before invoked method executes.
To fix that, move `Destroy(gameObject)` to the `ChangeScene` method :

```
void Die ()
{
    Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    EnemiesAlive--;

    if (EnemiesAlive <= 0)
    {
        Debug.Log ("LEVEL WON!");
        Invoke("ChangeScene",2f);
    }
}

void ChangeScene()
{
    Debug.Log ("Hello");
    loadToScene = 1;
    Destroy(gameObject);
    SceneManager.LoadScene (loadToScene);
}
```

You can optionally specify the time after which the object will be destroyed using an overload of `Destroy` method : `Destroy(gameObject, 1.0f)` ( will destroy object after one second ).

Comment: I would add an `else { Destroy(this); }` as well.